# How to use highchart boost library with D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, highcharts

I was using high-charts in my previous project but it has some licensing issue with industry so i am moving to D3 but i like their performance optimization specially using boost. How can i achieve same performance in D3.

Boost link:   https://code.highcharts.com/modules/boost.js

Below is sample code using boost.

```
{
    boost: {
        useGPUTranslations: true
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Boost'
    },

    series: [{
       boostThreshold: 1, // Boost when there are more than 1                     
                            // point in the chart.
        data: [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3]],
    }]
};
```

Can i use highcharts boost library as it has been designed to use in highcharts only or is there any way to use improve the performance using other library in D3?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, you can not use the `boost` module with other libraries than Highcharts.
The module is created by Highcharts developers and it is intended for use only with Highcharts.

Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module

Comment: But is there any other similar library which can boost performance of the d3 for handling big data?

Comment: @Manish, Sorry, but I do not know D3. I can help you with Highcharts if you have any questions.